# Redirect non www to www not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I have created an .htaccess file with 
the following code in order to achieve this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.lk[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.lk/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

but following http://example.lk doesn't redirect to www.example.lk
it failed and

[example.lk is only for example]

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Hi Michael , 
I tried it doesn't work

Comment: in particular for "I tried it doesn't work": -1.

Comment: In addition to http://www.example.com, you also need a DNS entry for http://example.com for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

`[nc]` has to be the third argument to `RewriteCond`, and therefore it needs to be preceded by at least one space.